# string format checking (with partly random string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to use regular expression to check if my string have the format like following:

```
mc_834faisd88979asdfas8897asff8790ds_oa_ids
mc_834fappsd58979asdfas8897asdf879ds_oa_ids
mc_834faispd8fs9asaas4897asdsaf879ds_oa_ids
mc_834faisd8dfa979asdfaspo97asf879ds_dv_ids
mc_834faisd111979asdfas88mp7asf879ds_dv_ids
mc_834fais00979asdfas8897asf87ggg9ds_dv_ids
```

The format is like `mc_<random string>_oa_ids` or `mc_<random string>_dv_ids` . How can I check if my string is in either of these two formats? And please explain the regular expression. thank you.

That's a string start with `mc_`, while end with `_oa_ids` or `dv_ids`, and have some **random string** in the middle.

**P.S.** the random string consists of alpha-beta letters and numbers.

**What I tried(I have no clue how to check the random string):**

```
/^mc_834faisd88979asdfas8897asff8790ds$_os_ids/
```

Comment: I have no clue how to check the random string, how can I try with no clue??? That's why I ask here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
^mc_[0-9a-z]+_(dv|oa)_ids$

^           matches at the start of the line the regex pattern is applied to. 
[0-9a-z]    matces alphabetic and numeric chars.
+           means that there should be one or more chars in this set
(dv|oa)     matches dv or oa
$           matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to. 
     also matches before the very last line break if the string ends with a line break.
```

Comment: The OP can put `{33}` instead of `+` if needs that kind of precision.

Comment: `^` and `$` are not the start and end of a string, they are the start and end of a line.

Comment: if I check the string format in ruby code, do I need to add // like mystr==/^mc_[0-9a-z]+_(dv|oa)_ids$/ ?

Comment: @tbuehlmann true. That depends what you are trying to match. It can be a file's or a line's start and end too.

Comment: @Leem.fin Yes you need to.

`s = "mc_834faisd88979asdfas8897asff8790ds_oa_ids"
r = /^mc_[0-9a-z]+_(dv|oa)_ids$/
m = r.match s`

Answer (score 0):

Give `/\Amc_\w*_(oa|dv)_ids\z/` a try. `\A` is the beginning of the string, `\z` the end. `\w*` are one or more of letters, numbers and underscores and `(oa|dv)` is either `oa` or `dv`.

A nice and simple way to test Ruby Regexps is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), might have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`/mc_834([a-z,0-9]*)_(oa|dv)_ids/g`

Example: http://regexr.com?2v9q7